# Managing source code of python packages using pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pipenv

I am using pipenv tool to manage the package and dependencies using the following shell script.

```
# Install pyvenv in the current project folder.
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1

# List of packages to be installed. 
declare -a arr=( \
    "elasticsearch" \
    "Flask" \
    "multiprocessing-logging" \
    "paramiko" \
    "python-json-logger" \
    "requests" \
    "traceback2" \
    "urllib3"
)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo Installing "$i"
   pipenv install $i
   # or do whatever with individual element of the array
done

pipenv lock
pipenv lock -r > req.txt
```

Alternatively, I can install the same packages using a pip install command as follows.

```
# Download python packages.
python3 -m pip install --target=./pkg -r ./requirements.pip
```

The advantage of using the `python3 -m pip install` is the use of `--target` option where the downloaded package source is available in the `pkg` folder, which can be moved around or commit to the git repo and point my project's `PYTHONPATH` env variable to.

However, there does not seem to be any option in pipenv which would save the downloaded packages, separate from the python virtual environment's site--packages` folder.

Note that I do not want to use the python virtual environment. I want a way to just download the packages source code. Using `pipenv` over `python3 -m pip install` for its obvious reasons.

Is this possible in pipenv? How it can be acheived in pipenv?

Comment: `pipenv` is a tool to work with `pip` in python virtual environments. Using `pipenv` contradicts your goal "*not … to use the python virtual environment*". `pipenv` cannot just download packages — it installs them int a virtual environment. `pip` alone can download packages in source or binary forms.